# Is there a way to set an event on the Calendar app that happens every week?

Tags: 16.04, calendar

I would like to add an event on the Calendar (for GNOME) app that happens every Wednesday, but I can't find any option that might allow that.

Is there a way to do it? If not, is there any Calendar app available that can manage this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `gnome-calendar` does not support creation of recurring events.

If you install `evolution` it does support creating such events, and events created in Evolution will also show up properly in gnome-calendar and in the date and time indicator in Unity.